# How to show that function belongs to a typedef in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, maintainability

If I have a typedef for a function pointer, such as

```
typedef void (* specialFunction) (void);
```

how can I show that I am declaring a function of that type, and not just coincidentally a function with the same signature?

I am not trying to enforce anything, just to make the code more legible (and maintainable), and make it obvious that the function declaration is say, a timer callback, or ISR routine.

Obviously, I can't

```
extern specialFunction mySpecialFunction(void);
```

but is there any way that I can use `specialFunction`  in the declaration, to distinguish `mySpecialFunction` from `myBoringlyNormalFunction`?

Comment: In C a function is a function is a function. There's nothing to make some functions (except `main`) more "special" than any other function, or to annotate functions to be used only for special purposes. All you have is comments and documentation.

Comment: For example, you can use like Adam Dunkels did in protothreads `PT_THREAD(example(struct pt *pt))` for declaring function with name `example`. More here: http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/

Comment: That sounds like it could be an answer, not just acomment (+1)

Comment: `extern specialFunction mySpecialFunction(void);` is legal code. It declares `mySpecialFunction` as a function which takes no parameters, and returns a function pointer. It's not clear from your question whether this is what you intended

Comment: Oops, sorry, no. That is not what I intended (+1). I intended to show that I can't declare a fucntoin with the signature of the typedef, using the typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void (* specialFunction) (void);` is a pointer type. You cannot declare a function of pointer type.  I assume you mean that you want to declare a function like `void f(void);` but based on that typedef.

If so, you could make the typedef be a function type:

```
typedef void specialFunction(void);
```

Then you can declare a function of that type and a pointer to such function like this:

```
specialFunction func_name;

specialFunction *p_func = &func_name;
```

Many people feel that avoiding pointer typedefs makes code easier to read, because the presence of the `*` symbol clearly indicates whether or not we are working with a pointer.

Comment: That is good ! Then I can declare a second typdef, which is a pointer to the first, for passing such functions as parameters (e.g. when registering a callback)

Comment: @Mawg You could, but my recommendation is to write `specialFunction *` instead of using another typedef, because then it is more obvious that the type is a pointer type

Comment: Agreed. I shall start to introduce this style to our team.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything in this. However, for visual representation, you can use self definitions like Adam Dunkels in [protothreads](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/):

```
typedef void (* specialFunction) (void);
#define TIMERCALLBACK(x)         specialFunction x
```

and then declare function like this:

```
TIMERCALLBACK(mycallback(void)) {
    //do your job
}
```

This is just one way how to represent function as `timer callback`for example.

Comment: What is stopping you from declaring `TIMERCALLBACK(mycallback(int))` which then isn't a specialFunction?

Comment: I did not quite understand your question here.

Comment: You're not actually defining `mycallback` to be `void mycallback(void)` and thus be the same type as specialFunction - you're declaring it to return a `specialFunction` which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: This is true, it can be easuly used just with `void`. But in C is no way to do what he want, thus I showed him another principle how to do visual representation.

Comment: This code declares `mycallback` as a function which returns a function pointer ; however I think OP wanted to declare `mycallback` as a function returning `void`

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare functions like that, only variables. But you can use a macro to ensure your functions are declared correctly like this.

```
typedef void (* specialFunction) (void);
#define SPECIALFUNCTION(x) void x(void)

extern SPECIALFUNCTION(mycallback);

int main(void)
    {
    specialFunction foo=mycallback;
    foo();
    }

SPECIALFUNCTION(mycallback)
    {
    printf("test\n");
    }
```